# Heroku does not load assets from asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

In my Rails app I have css and js that is unique to each action.

So users#new has its own css. It's named `users_new.css.scss`.

I deployed my app to Heroku, and Heroku isn't loading any of the assets. You can see the errors [here](http://timelino.herokuapp.com/). How do I fix this so Heroku correctly precompiles and loads the assets?

I read through [Heroku's docs on using the asset pipeline](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline), but didn't see any solution.

Comment: do you have (gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production") in your Gemfile ?

Comment: That'll do it, thanks :)

Comment: Am posting it as Answer so that other programmer may benefit from it in future.

Comment: Actually looks like this doesn't load page specific assets. (See the errors in the console on the page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Precompilation**

The problem is your `timelines_index.js` is not [precompiled](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets):

[image]

The way you can tell this is a problem is that when you call the asset in your `layout` (which I presume you're doing with the correct path helpers), Rails will automatically reference the latest precompiled version of that file (hence why `application.js` has the appended [MD5 fingerprint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark))

I believe you'll need to add your custom files to your [`precompiled_assets`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) array:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['timelines_index.js']
```

This will give Rails the ability to precompile those assets individually, allowing you to call them in your layout:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag "timelines_index" %>
```

This will have to be done for all the custom asset files you wish to call in your layout.

---

[**Manifest**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives)

As mentioned by `Anil`, you may wish to use the `manifest` system of Rails to concatenate all your asset files into their respective `application` files.

This will quash the need to append the files to the Rails `precompile` array, allowing you to call a single file for your various assets:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in your Gemfile

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Comment: Actually looks like the page specific assets are still not being loaded.

Comment: In production mode, all your assets will be compiled in application.js file

Comment: donot try to load css and js explicitly

Comment: For this particular app, I am loading JS and CSS specifically for pages. That is why I'm having this unique problem :)

Comment: Then why you are using asset pipeline ? whole purpose of asset pipeline is to load all your asset in one file.